# ChartJS hide labels on small screen sizes

Tags: javascript, chart.js, responsive

I have a problem hiding xAxes and yAxes labels on small screen sizes (mobile phones). I know there is this option:

```
options:
        {
            scales:
            {
                xAxes: [{
                    ticks:{
                        display: false
                    }

                }];
            }
        }
```

But if i use it in the onResize function like this

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("chart");

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    //chart data and options,

   onResize: function(myChart, size) {

   if (size.height < 140) {
        options:
        {
            scales:
            {
                xAxes: [{
                    ticks:{
                        display: false
                    }

                }];
            }
        }
     }
});
```

But it does not work on resize. Is hiding labels onResize even the right solution? I am testing on with Chrome responsive mode and on resize works, but would it if accessed from mobile phones?

Can somebody please help me with this problem and point me int the right direction?

Thanks, Gregor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a try with

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    //chart data and options,

   onResize: function(myChart, size) {

     var showTicks = (size.height < 140) ? false : true;

     myChart.options = {
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        display: showTicks
                    }
                }];
            }
     };

  }
});
```

Comment: Works great. But I am still puzzled if this code will hide labels on mobile devices. Does onResize actually occur when accessing from mobile?

Comment: Its the code for resize event that is defined in onResize. You can have a code while creating the control that checks for the size and makes the decision right then.

Comment: Yeah the other answer should work to define it while creating the control.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
onResize: function(myChart, size) {
    myChart.options.scales.xAxes[0].ticks.display = (size.height >= 140);
}
```

In order to get the option on load on mobile, you should do this:

```
function isMobileDevice(){
    return ( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent));
}

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    options :
        scales:
        {
            xAxes: [{
                ticks:{
                    display: !isMobileDevice()
                }

            }];
        } 
})
```

Comment: Works great. But I am still puzzled if this code will hide labels on mobile devices. Does onResize actually occur when accessing from mobile?

Comment: I don't know... I believe this function will run only when you resize the window. If you want to start the chart with the ticks hidden in mobile, you should do this when defining the options. I'll update.

Comment: Check this out.

Comment: @GregorKoprivnikar don't forget to pick an accepted answer if it helped ;)

Comment: I have one more problem with this solution. For example: Android runs both  on tablets and mobile phones, but on tablets there is enough space to display labels. Do you maybe have a simple solution for that? Maybe the best solution would be to write a simular function for check screens sizes?

Comment: Gregor, it'd surely be better. Where I defined the `display: !isMobileDevice()` you can change it into a conditional. Something like `display: window.screen.width > 120`

Comment: Thanks! Tried to hide dataset label for mobile phone and just work with isMobileDevice function! I've tried many options others but it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

For `Angular` you can make the logic like this...
the `screen.width` will counted as your viewport width

```js
  canvas: any;
  ctx: any;
  legend: any;
  font: any;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.canvas = document.getElementById('tpChart');
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.legend = (screen.width < 575) ? false : true; //when viewport will be under 575px
    this.font = (screen.width < 1200) ? 14 : 16; //when viewport will be under 1200px
    let tpChart = new Chart(this.ctx, {
      type: 'doughnut',
      data: {
        datasets: [{
          borderWidth: 2,
          data: [70, 50, 40, 30],
          backgroundColor: [
            '#00CDB6',
            '#F08C2E',
            '#0F9AF0',
            '#F16C51',
          ],
        }],
        labels: [
          'United Kingdom',
          'Bangladesh',
          'United States',
          'Others',
        ]
      },
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        cutoutPercentage: 65,
        spanGaps: false,
        legend: {
          display: this.legend, //This will work dynamatically
          position: "right",
          align: "center",
          labels: {
            fontColor: '#484848',
            boxWidth: 10,
            fontSize: this.font, //This will work dynamatically
            fontFamily: "Cabin",
            padding: 25,
            usePointStyle: true
          },
          
        }
      },
    });
  }
```