# How to hide Chart.js data labels for small screens

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to hide data labels generated by the [data labels plugin](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/) for small screens.

I thought that I could use the onResize property of chartjs and set display to false when the width got small. This is much like the hide labels solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47791250/chartjs-hide-labels-on-small-screen-sizes).

Unfortunately, I've not been able to get this to work. I have the following [CodePen](https://codepen.io/mdeggers/full/qvqYWq) that doesn't work.

```
var moneyFormat = wNumb({
    decimals: 0,
    thousand: ',',
    prefix: '$',
    negativeBefore: '-'
});

var percentFormat = wNumb({
    decimals: 0,
    suffix: '%',
    negativeBefore: '-'
});

/*
 * Unregister chartjs-plugins-datalabels - not really necessary for this use case
 */
Chart.plugins.unregister(ChartDataLabels);

var doughnutdata = {
    labels: ['Housing',
        'Food',
        'Transportation',
        'Clothing',
        'Healthcare',
        'Childcare',
        'Misc'],
    datasets: [
        {
            backgroundColor: [
                '#9B2A00',
                '#5B5C90',
                '#6B8294',
                '#1A6300',
                '#BE0000',
                '#B8A853',
                '#64A856'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                '#FFFFFF',
                '#FFFFFF',
                '#FFFFFF',
                '#FFFFFF',
                '#FFFFFF',
                '#FFFFFF',
                '#FFFFFF'
            ],
            data: [88480, 57680, 40050, 18430, 23860, 25840, 17490]
        }
    ]
};

var chartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: true,
    legend: {
        labels: {
            boxWidth: 20
        }
    },
    tooltips: {
        callbacks: {
            label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                var index = tooltipItem.index;
                return data.labels[index] + ': ' + moneyFormat.to(data.datasets[0].data[index]) + '';
            }
        }
    },
    plugins: {
        datalabels: {
            anchor: 'end',
            backgroundColor: function (context) {
                return context.dataset.backgroundColor;
            },
            borderColor: 'white',
            borderRadius: 25,
            borderWidth: 1,
            color: 'white',
            font: {
                size: 10
            },
            formatter: function (value, pieID) {
                var sum = 0;
                var dataArr = pieID.chart.data.datasets[0].data;
                dataArr.map(function (data) {
                    sum += data;
                });
                var percentage = percentFormat.to((value * 100 / sum));
                return percentage;
            }
        }
    }
};

var doughnutID = document.getElementById('doughnutchart').getContext('2d');

var pieChart = new Chart(doughnutID, {
    plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: doughnutdata,
    options: chartOptions,
    onResize: function(chart, size) {
        var showLabels = (size.width < 500) ? false : true;
        chart.options = {
            plugins: {
                datalabels: {
                    display: showLabels
                }
            }
        };
    }
});
```

Any ideas concerning what I'm doing wrong (and fixes) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual, as soon as I post a question I come up with an answer. One solution using inline plugin definitions is given at the following [CodePen](https://codepen.io/mdeggers/full/rRjgLj). If you put a browser into developer mode and shrink the window to less than 540 px, the data labels will vanish.

The code is shown below:

```
"use strict";
/* global Chart */
/* global wNumb */
/* global ChartDataLabels */
/*
 * Unregister chartjs-plugins-datalabels - not really necessary for this use case
 */
Chart.plugins.unregister(ChartDataLabels);

var moneyFormat = wNumb({
  decimals: 0,
  thousand: ",",
  prefix: "$",
  negativeBefore: "-"
});

var percentFormat = wNumb({
  decimals: 0,
  suffix: "%",
  negativeBefore: "-"
});

var doughnutdata = {
  labels: [
    "Housing",
    "Food",
    "Transportation",
    "Clothing",
    "Healthcare",
    "Childcare",
    "Misc"
  ],
  datasets: [
    {
      backgroundColor: [
        "#9B2A00",
        "#5B5C90",
        "#6B8294",
        "#1A6300",
        "#BE0000",
        "#B8A853",
        "#64A856"
      ],
      borderColor: [
        "#FFFFFF",
        "#FFFFFF",
        "#FFFFFF",
        "#FFFFFF",
        "#FFFFFF",
        "#FFFFFF",
        "#FFFFFF"
      ],
      data: [88480, 57680, 40050, 18430, 23860, 25840, 17490]
    }
  ]
};

var chartOptions = {
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: true,
  legend: {
    labels: {
      boxWidth: 20
    }
  },
  tooltips: {
    callbacks: {
      label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
        var index = tooltipItem.index;
        return (
          data.labels[index] +
          ": " +
          moneyFormat.to(data.datasets[0].data[index]) +
          ""
        );
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: {
    datalabels: {
      anchor: "end",
      backgroundColor: function(context) {
        return context.dataset.backgroundColor;
      },
      borderColor: "white",
      borderRadius: 25,
      borderWidth: 1,
      color: "white",
      font: {
        size: 10
      },
      formatter: function(value, pieID) {
        var sum = 0;
        var dataArr = pieID.chart.data.datasets[0].data;
        dataArr.map(function(data) {
          sum += data;
        });
        var percentage = percentFormat.to(value * 100 / sum);
        return percentage;
      }
    }
  }
};

var doughnutID = document.getElementById("doughnutchart").getContext("2d");

var pieChart = new Chart(doughnutID, {
  plugins: [
    ChartDataLabels,
    {
      beforeLayout: function(chart) {
        var showLabels = (chart.width) > 500 ? true : false;
        chart.options.plugins.datalabels.display = showLabels;
      }
    },
    {
      onresize: function(chart) {
        var showLabels = (chart.width) > 500 ? true : false;
        chart.options.plugins.datalabels.display = showLabels;
      }
    }
  ],
  type: "doughnut",
  data: doughnutdata,
  options: chartOptions
});
```

I hope that this is useful.

Answer (score 6):

Responsiveness can be implemented using [scriptable options](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/guide/options.html#scriptable-options) and in your case, you would use a function for the `display` option that returns `false` if the chart is smaller than a specific size. ([Example](https://codepen.io/simonbrunel/pen/gEXOgK)):

```js
options: {
  plugins: {
    datalabels: {
      display: function(context) {
        return context.chart.width > 500;
      }
    }
  }
}
```